# Is is possible to toggle an Event subscription in one line? (Subscribe/Unsubscribe)

Tags: c#, events

I have an application that will regularly create objects that will subscribe to a statically referenced class' events like so:

```
protected override void OnSubscribeToggle(bool subscribe)
{
    if (subscribe)
    {
        SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueAChanged += OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueAChanged;
        SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueBChanged += OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueBChanged;
        SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueCChanged += OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueCChanged;
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueAChanged -= OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueAChanged;
        SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueBChanged -= OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueBChanged;
        SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueCChanged -= OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueCChanged;
        //...
    }
}
```

My problem is that with this setup I have to have an almost complete copy of the same list of subscriptions to either subscribe or unsubscribe. Without complex unit testing, making sure all the lines were identical and correct comes down to just eye balling it.

Is there a way to toggle subscriptions to events so that I don't have to (pretty much) copy-paste the same lines and hope they match up for all classes that do this?

What I'm looking to do is something like the following:

```
// My goal (if this were valid code)
protected override void OnSubscribeToggle(bool subscribe)
{
    SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueAChanged (subscribe ? (+=) : (-=)) OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueAChanged;
    SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueBChanged (subscribe ? (+=) : (-=)) OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueBChanged;
    SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueCChanged (subscribe ? (+=) : (-=)) OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueCChanged;
    //...
}
```

Comment: First example is perfect.

Comment: There is no direct way to do that. Maybe you'd like to carefully inspect your architecture in order to avoid these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ideas is to organize code in a way that it will be easy to copy-paste and thus follow some pattern (while it still be possible to make mistake, if somebody likes inventing a wheel).

So you will need a lot of methods like this one:

```
    private void SomeValueAChangedSubscribe(bool subscribe)
    {
        if (subscribe)
        {
            SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueAChanged += OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueAChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            SomeSingleton.Instance.SomeValueAChanged -= OnSomeSingleton_SomeValueAChanged;
        }
    }
```

Then, you will need storage for all such methods:

```
    private Action<bool>[] GetSubscribeMethods()
    {
        return new Action<bool>[]
        {
            SomeValueAChangedSubscribe,
            SomeValueBChangedSubscribe,
            SomeValueCChangedSubscribe,
            ...
        };
    }
```

And then use it like this:

```
    protected override void OnSubscribeToggle(bool subscribe)
    {
        foreach (var subscribeMethod in GetSubscribeMethods())
        {
            subscribeMethod(subscribe);
        }
    }
```

So to add new subscription you will need to copy-paste subscription logic & add new method to arrays of subscription methods.

Not sure if that will be better, but high chances that it will be harder to make mistake here.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea! I went with the base class essentially offering the virtual method `protected override IEnumerable<SubUnsubActionPair> OnSubscribeToggle()
    {
        yield return new SubUnsubActionPair(
            () => ...sub,
            () => ...unsub);
    }`